# How to find the critical point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> > find  the critical points of the nonlinear system of differential
> >     equations:
>
> $\frac{dx}{dt}= y(x^2+1)$
>
> $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2xy^2$

My attempt : i convert them into jacobian matrix

here $f(x) = y(x^2+1)$ and $g(x) = 2xy^2$

$\begin{bmatrix} f_x & f_y \\g_x & g_y \end{bmatrix}$ Now im getting $\begin{bmatrix} 2xy & x^2+1 \\ 2y^2 & 4xy \end{bmatrix}$

After that im not able to proceed further

Comment: Isn’t a critical point just a point where derivative is 0?

Comment: @jasmine: The critical points are the line $y = 0$.  This makes the eigenvalues $0$ for all $x$. It might be easier to just draw a phase portrait.

Comment: @Moo oks .....ok